# REGEX for complete word matching

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

OK So i am confused (obviously)

I'm trying to return rows (from Oracle) where a text field contains a complete word, not just the substring.

a simple example is the word 'I'.

Show me all rows where the string contains the word 'I', but not simply where 'I' is a substring somewhere as in `'%I%'`

so I wrote what i thought would be a simple regex:

```
select REGEXP_INSTR(upper(description), '\bI\b') from mytab;
```

expecting that I should be detected with word boundaries.  I get no results (or rather the result 0 for each row.

what i expect:

- 'I am the Administrator' -> 1
- 'I'm the administrator' -> 0
- 'Am I the administrator' -> 1
- 'It is the infamous administrator' -> 0
- 'The adminisrtrator, tis I' -> 1

isn't the /b supposed to find the contained string by word boundary?

tia

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle REGEXP\_LIKE and word boundaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567700/oracle-regexp-like-and-word-boundaries)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that \b is not supported by your flavor of regex :

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#i1007670

Therefore you could do something like :

```
(^|\s)word(\s|$)
```

To at least ensure that your "word" is separated by some whitespace or it's the whole string.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle doesn't support word boundary anchors, but even if it did, you wouldn't get the desired result: `\b` matches between an alphanumeric character and a non-alphanumeric character. The exact definition of what an alnum is differs between implementations, but in most flavors, it's `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (.NET also considers Unicode letters/digits).

So there are two boundaries around the `I` in `%I%`.

If you define your word boundary as "whitespace before/after the word", then you could use

```
(^|\s)I(\s|$)
```

which would also work at the start/end of the string.

Comment: Thanks.  This variant is giving me pretty good results: '(^|\W)TO(\W|$)'  the \W is 'non-word' characters...

Comment: But that would pick up `%I%`.

Comment: i meant that %I% as an example of the comparison you might make in a LIKE statement... sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle native regex support](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix.htm#g693775) is limited. `\b` or `<` cannot be used as word delimiters. You may want Oracle Text for word search.