# RegExp_Replace only numeric words in PLSQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I need help to replace the numeric words with null.

Example:

1. Dustun 0989 LLC
2. Dustun_0989 LLC
3. 457 Dustun LLC
4. 457_Dustun LLC
5. 334 Dunlop 987

Output:

1. Dustun LLC
2. Dustun_0989 LLC
3. Dustun LLC
4. 457_Dustun LLC
5. Dunlop

Comment: no .. the below answer provided by you is good enough and it works like a charm...many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get it done with regular expressions. For example, something like this:

```
WITH the_table AS (SELECT 'Dustun 0989 LLC' field FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'Dustun_0989 LLC' field FROM dual
                   UNION 
                   SELECT '457 Dustun LLC' field FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT '457_Dustun LLC' field FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'Dunlop 987' field FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT '222 333 ADIS GROUP 422 123' field FROM dual)                   
SELECT field, TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(field,'((^|\s|\W)(\d|\s)+($|\s|\W))',' '))
FROM the_table
```

Note that (^|\s|\W) and ($|\s|\W) are Oracle regexp equivalent to \b, as explained in [Oracle REGEXP_LIKE and word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567700/oracle-regexp-like-and-word-boundaries)

Where:

- (^|\s|\W) is either the beginning of line, a blank space or a non-word character.
- (\s|\d)+ is a combination of one or more digits and spaces.
- ($|\s|\W) is either the end of line, a blank space or a non-word character.

Comment: 222 333 ADIS GROUP 422 123 is getting converted to 333 ADIS GROUP 123, ideally it should be ADIS GROUP

Comment: @meet I just edited my answer to include this case, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

No need for PL/SQL here, a simple SQL statement will do:

```
regexp_replace(the_column, '(\s[0-9]+\s)|(^[0-9]+\s)|(\s[0-9]+$)', ' ')
```

This does the replaces any number of digits between two whitespaces or digits at the start of the value followed by a whitespace or a whitespace followed by digits at the end of the input value.

The following:

```
with sample_data (the_column) as 
(
    select 'Dustun 0989 LLC' from dual union all
    select 'Dustun_0989 LLC' from dual union all
    select '457 Dustun LLC' from dual union all
    select '457_Dustun LLC' from dual union all
    select '334 Dunlop 987' from dual
)
select regexp_replace(the_column, '(\s[0-9]+\s)|(^[0-9]+\s)|(\s[0-9]+$)', ' ') as new_value
from sample_data
```

will output:

```
NEW_VALUE      
---------------
Dustun LLC     
Dustun_0989 LLC
 Dustun LLC    
457_Dustun LLC 
 Dunlop
```

To get rid of the leading (or trailing) spaces, use the `trim` function: `trim(regexp_replace(...))`

Comment: Can you modify it so that it should replace the numeric value for more that one consecutive occurance.

Comment: 222 333 ADIS GROUP 422 123 is getting converted to 333 ADIS GROUP 123

Answer (score 0):

This will work too

```
select regexp_replace(text,'[0-9]') from dual
```

Comment: No, it will not work, because it will change `Dustun_0989 LLC` to `Dustun_ LLC` which is not what meet wants