# Oracle regexp_like word boundaries multiple words workaround

Tags: oracle, regexp-like, word-boundaries

As you know Oracle POSIX implementation of regexes does not support word boundaries. One workaround is suggested here:
[Oracle REGEXP_LIKE and word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567700/oracle-regexp-like-and-word-boundaries)

However it does not work if I want to, for instance select all 4 character strings. Consider this, for example:

```
myvar:=regexp_substr('test test','(^|\s|\W)[\S]{4}($|\s|\W)')
```

This obviously selects only the first occurrence. I do not know how to do this in the Oracle world, although normally it is simply `(\b)[\S]{4}(\b)`. The problem is that most woraround rely on some nonexistent feature, like lookaround etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
select xmlcast(xmlquery('for $token in ora:tokenize(concat(" ",$in)," ")
                where string-length($token) = $size
                return $token' passing 'test test' as "in", 4 as "size" returning content) as varchar2(2000)) word from dual;
```

Xquery and FLWOR  expresion.

`concat(" ",$in)` - workaround if input string is null or it has only 1 matchting word.

`ora:tokenize` - tokenize string by "space"

`string-length($token) = $size` check if token has appropriate length.

`xmlcast` - convert xmltype to varchar2

Easy ? Any question:)

Comment: I have seen so many wonderful solutions using Oracle XML, but I am totally ignorant about it. Can someone recommend a book or web site to get me started?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
  str     VARCHAR2(200) := 'test test';
  pattern VARCHAR2(200) := '(\w+)($|\s+|\W+)';
  match   VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. REGEXP_COUNT( str, pattern ) LOOP
    match := REGEXP_SUBSTR( str, pattern, 1, i, NULL, 1 );
    IF LENGTH( match ) = 4 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( match );
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

or (without using `REGEXP_COUNT` or the 6th parameter of `REGEXP_SUBSTR` that was introduced in 11G):

```
DECLARE
  str              VARCHAR2(200) := 'test test';
  pattern CONSTANT VARCHAR2(3)   := '\w+';
  match            VARCHAR2(200);
  i                NUMBER(4,0)   := 1;
BEGIN
  match := REGEXP_SUBSTR( str, pattern, 1, i );
  WHILE match IS NOT NULL LOOP
    IF LENGTH( match ) = 4 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( match );
    END IF;
    i     := i + 1;
    match := REGEXP_SUBSTR( str, pattern, 1, i );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Output**:

```
test
test
```

If you want to use this in SQL then you can easily translate it into a pipelined function or a function that returns a collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, I am on 10g and REGEXP_COUNT is not available. I think they introduced it in 11g.

Comment: @Dimiter Added a (hopefully) Oracle 10g solution.

Comment: @MTO: Thank you very much! Much appreciated!