# Check for a presence of word in string by Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I tried to check the string for presence of specific word by regular expression `'\b<word>\b'`, but it seems that `\b` anchor doesn't work in REGEXP_SUBSTR:

E.g. to check for a word `ABC`:

```
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR ('A, AB, ABC,ABCD', '\bABC\b') FROM DUAL;
```

but the result here is (null). What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want to do with the `\b`? Do you only need to only get `ABC`, excluding, for example, `xABC`, `ABCy`, `xABCY`?

Comment: Yes, I want to check for whole word - in my case, for word 'ABC', not a string 'ABC' as part of word 'ABCD'.

Comment: Oracle regex does not support `\b` construct. You need to use `(^|[^[:alnum:]_])word($|[^[:alnum:]_])` or `(^|\W)word($|\W)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle REGEXP\_LIKE and word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567700/oracle-regexp-like-and-word-boundaries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a string contains a given word, exactly, and assuming that the only characters that can separate two words in the string are a comma and a space, all you need to do is handle these two characters, even thinking to the beginning and the end of the string:

```
SELECT 1 from dual
where REGEXP_LIKE ('A, AB, ABC,ABCD', '(^| |,)ABC(,|$| )')
```

How it works:

`(^| |,)` means that the word can by preceded by nothing (the beginning of the string), by a comma or a space;

similarly `(,|$| )` means that the word can be followed by a comma, nothing (the end of the string) or a space

Comment: Thank you, it works! But why I can't use `\b` anchor to match a word boundary positions: `\bABC\b`?