# Need Regular expression to match exact table name in source code in Oracle 12cR1

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle12c, regexp-like

I am using **Oracle 12cR1**. I need a REGEX pattern to exactly match a given table name from Oracle source code (i.e) the match must not be preceded or succeeded by a number or an alphabet or an underscore symbol.

I have created a dummy source code and tried the below. It is not fetching all the desired records. What am I missing? Is there a REGEX pattern for this?

**Test code:**

```
with names as (
select 'mytabname' tabname from dual union all
select 'mytabname1' from dual union all
select 'mytabname_' from dual union all
select 'mytabnameX' from dual union all
select '1mytabname' from dual union all
select '_mytabname' from dual union all
select 'Xmytabname' from dual union all
select '1mytabname_' from dual union all
select '1mytabnameX' from dual union all
select '_mytabname1' from dual union all
select 'Xmytabname1' from dual union all
select '_mytabnameX' from dual union all
select 'Xmytabname_' from dual union all
select '_mytabname_' from dual union all
select 'XmytabnameX' from dual union all
select '1mytabname1' from dual union all
select ' mytabname_' from dual union all
select '_mytabname ' from dual union all
select ' mytabname ' from dual union all
select ' mytabnameX' from dual union all
select 'Xmytabname ' from dual union all
select ' mytabname1' from dual union all
select '1mytabname ' from dual union all
select '.mytabname ' from dual union all
select ' mytabname.' from dual union all
select '.mytabname.' from dual union all
select '*mytabname' from dual union all
select ' mytabname*' from dual union all
select '*mytabname*' from dual union all
select 'defmytabnameabc' from dual)
select 'start'||tabname||'end' from names
where regexp_like(tabname, '[^a-zA-Z0-9_](mytabname)[^a-zA-Z0-9_]');
```

**Output:**

```
start mytabname end
start.mytabname end
start mytabname.end
start.mytabname.end
start mytabname*end
start*mytabname*end
```

The output misses the following records

```
startmytabnameend
start*mytabnameend
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_source
 WHERE regexp_like(text, '(\W|^)' || 'employees' || '(\W|$)', 'i');
```

find the details of Regex here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52441424/7998591

`'i'` is for ignore case and you may omit if you wish.

[**Demo for your data**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=356ac66c71c8c05dcf278f052f8142fb)