# query to return all records that have a reoccuring string/number

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for assistance in finding records that have a reoccurring string/number in an attibute due to input mismanagement.  For example, the table will look similar to the following:

```
ID|stuff
1 | 23 jackson jackson st
2 | 89 jackson st
3 | 1 1 jackson st
4 | 66 jackson st
```

I'd like the return to look like the following:

```
ID|stuff
1 | 23 jackson jackson st
3 | 1 1 jackson st
```

please note, in the above example, 's' doesnt cause it to return in id 2, even though its in both jackSon and St.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are the matches you want always consecutive repeats?

Comment: What if it's `jackson st jackson` or `jackson st st`?

Comment: You will run into all sorts of trouble with this, no matter what solution you consider. There will be situations you didn't think about, especially if you are looking to remove repeated patterns that are not consecutive. For example, if you want to remove **12** from **12 jackson 12 street**, what do you do with **12 jackson st apartment 12**? Another example - **Walla Walla** is a city in Washington state in the U.S. Should it be shown as **Walla**?

Comment: Not too familiar with oracle, but what if you split them into column, then use rank function to rank each space separated word (partition by id) such that repeated words get the same rank, then use aggregation to filter ids where count(rank) doesn't equal count(distinct rank), finally join on those ids.

Comment: Yeah i see that walla walla would be an issue; however, we would actually manually review the returns and if it is legit would leave it be.  this is basically a query to return possible situations that we would then look over manually.

Comment: You still didn't tell us - are you only looking for consecutive occurrences (meaning, the second "copy" immediately follows the first?) Are you looking for situations where the second "copy" may be followed by comma, or any other non-alphanumeric characters, or just space?

Answer (score 3):

You can use back-references in Oracle regular expressions.  I *think* this does what you want:

```
select *
from t
where regexp_like(' ' || stuff, ' ([^ ]+) .*\1');
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1120fe856f541f955ccaf0723863af25) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This will report false positives. For example: `'3 s main st'`. If the first "repeated" word is a **sub**string of a longer word in the remaining string, the string will match the regular expression.

Comment: is there any way to get around it?

Comment: For this example, add a space after the back reference to match the space after the group: `' ([^ ]+) .*\1 '`

Comment: @Gary_W - that assumes that the second occurrence is not at the end of the string.

Comment: @mathguy You are right, this example should end in `( |$)`: `' ([^ ]+) .*\1( |$)'`

Comment: @user7002207 . . . You need to ask a clearer question on what exactly constitutes a duplicate.  As the SQL Fiddle shows, this answers the question that you asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `WHERE` predicate

```
where regexp_like(stuff, '(^|\W)(\w+)($|\W).*\2')
```

Note that initial and traling group `(^|\W)` and `($|\W)` means start/ end of the string *or* a non-word charater will delimit the second group - the first instance of the duplicated word.

The second group is defined as a `(\w+)` one or more *word charters*.

You may want alternatively use `\s` (white space) instead of `\W` - see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/Perl-influenced-Extensions-in-Oracle-Regular-Expressions.html#GUID-2D2B8DEB-1343-4DA3-BBC1-5A5C79A5FC20) for further details.

Here sample data returned by this regexp addressing also the non-word delimiters.

*You should also not underestimate tabs and other white stuff, that the simple solution ignore*.

```
23 jackson jackson st
1 1 jackson st
68 jackson.st.jackson
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7567871/4808122) answer with a similar topic.